# pass id to a tag href in modal(bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

hy, i want to pass my id to a tag href in my modal(bootstrap), for know i using this to past my id from my modal button :

```
        modal.find('#down').attr('href', function(i, href) {
            return href + div.data('id');
        });
```

this is my a tag:

```
  <a type="button" id="down" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/aprove/download/">Berkas</a>
```

this is my modal button:

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Lihat" data-id="<?php echo $q->id_project ?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lihat-data">                                                        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ubah-data" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></i></button>                                                  </a>
```

the problem its, every time i click the modal button, my a tag(href) will add previous id to the new one, like this:

first modal:

```
href="http://localhost/pe//aprove/download/4"
```

second modal:

```
href="http://localhost/pe//aprove/download/41"
```

i need to refresh the table to make it just get their own id

Comment: What is modal? Where is it's code? Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do something like

```html
<a type="button" id="down" data-href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/aprove/download/">Berkas</a>
```

and read the data attribute

```js
var anchor = modal.find('#down')
anchor.attr('href', anchor.data('href') + div.data('id'));
```